# How to solve the problem that "Timed out waiting for a response from the computer" when using VNC viewer to connect VNC server?

Tags: vnc-server

I have make sure the VNC server has been started and I have check the port of 5901 and that it is Listening and I open the firewall for this port.But I also can't connect the server.Can you help me?Thank you!